# Seeking help constructing Purim Torah about EH"'E 22:13

Tags: sources-mekorot, purim, shulchan-aruch, humor

A friend drew my attention to [this direct quote](http://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%96%D7%A8_%D7%9B%D7%91_%D7%99%D7%92) from the (very real) שלחן ערוך:‎

> תקנו חכמים שיהיו הנשים מספרות זו עם זו בבית הכסא, כדי שלא יכנס שם איש ויתייחד עמהן. (וי"א דוקא בימיהם שהיו בתי כסאות בשדות, אבל בזמן הזה שהן בעיר, אין לחוש) (הגהות מיימוני פרק ב' מהלכות איסור ביאה):‏

I'm looking for help constructing this into hilarious/groanworthy Purim Torah.

Essentially, it boils down to that the sages decreed that women should speak to each other in the ladies' room.

I'm looking for other sources and some creative wit to help me spin this into something I'll probably regret later.

Comment: 2 things come to mind but I leave any and all spinning up to you.  9 kavin of sicha went to the ladies, and it just so happens to be that the ladies room is always waaay nicer than the men's room.

Comment: The rabbis decreed that women give each other haircuts in the bathroom?

Comment: You can't say the Bracha on Sefira in the bathroom!

Comment: I second the close vote

Comment: @IshPloniViKohen That was actually how I read it the first time!

Comment: I wish this comment discussion was less disjointed.

Comment: @DoubleAA you can vote now to close as a regular user'

Comment: I think this question belongs on chat

Comment: Can I put in my two cents before the fifth close vote is submitted? I'm asking for specific help with a Jewish learning question. I know it's for Purim Torah, but for many Purim Torah is part of Jewish life and learning.

Comment: I think that this question could be answerable like a [tag:product-recommendation] question if it provided more detail about what it's looking for and how to objectively evaluate and compare answers.